# Trouble Calculating Vertex Normals (in C++, for openGL project)

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

i have a project where i must read an OBJ file and display a model using GLUT. im reading and displaying the model fine but i can't get the normals to work ok. I have saved all faces in a Faces[] array of 3 vtx[] (=points) arrays with x,y,z and a normal also with x,y,z coordinates. I calculate 2 vectors that correspond to each one of the 3 Vertexes of each face, the i get their Cross Product, I Normalize it and I add its x,y,z coodrdinates to the Normal parameter (so that if there is more than one Normal for each Vertex we add them an get somthing like the average of all the normal vectors) and I normalize again. When i print out the some Normal coordinates to see what happens it prints out 0,0,(something weird) as x,y,z. Anyway here's the code.

```
     for (int i = 0 ; i<triangle_index; i++)
    {
        float ux,uy,uz,vx,vy,vz,nn,nx,ny,nz;

    //get vectors from first vertex of face
        ux= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].x ;
        uy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].y ;
        uz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].z ;

        vx= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].x ;
        vy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].y ;
        vz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].z ;
   //CrossProduct 
        nx = (uy*vz) - (vy*uz);
        ny = (vx*uz) - (ux*vz);
        nz = (ux*vy) - (uy*vx);
   //Length         
        nn = sqrt((nx*nx)+(ny*ny)+(nz*nz));
   //Normalize                  
        nx = nx/nn;
        ny = ny/nn;
        nz = nz/nn;
    //Save to Vertex.Normal (plus any previous data)
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.x =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.x + nx);
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.y =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.y + ny);
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.z =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.z + nz);

  //get length again 

  nn =  sqrt((Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.x*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.x)+(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.y*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.y)+(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.z*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.z));

    //Normalize again

        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.x =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.x)/nn;
        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.y =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.y)/nn;
        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.z =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].norm.z)/nn;

   //---------------Same For Second Vertex of the Same Face---------------------------/

        ux= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].x ;
        uy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].y ;
        uz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].z ;

        vx= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].x ;
        vy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].y ;
        vz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].z ;

        nx = (uy*vz) - (vy*uz);
        ny = (vx*uz) - (ux*vz);
        nz = (ux*vy) - (uy*vx);

        nn = sqrt((nx*nx)+(ny*ny)+(nz*nz));

        nx = nx/nn;
        ny = ny/nn;
        nz = nz/nn;

        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.x =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.x + nx);
        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.y =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.y + ny);
        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.z =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.z + nz);

    nn =sqrt((Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.x*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.x)+(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.y*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.y)+(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.z*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.z));

        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.x =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.x)/nn;
        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.y =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.y)/nn;
        Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.z =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].norm.z)/nn;
    //------------------Again for number three--------------------------------
    ux= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].x ;
    uy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].y ;
    uz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].z ;

    vx= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].x ;
    vy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].y ;
    vz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].z ;

    nx = (uy*vz) - (vy*uz);
    ny = (vx*uz) - (ux*vz);
    nz = (ux*vy) - (uy*vx);

    nn = sqrt((nx*nx)+(ny*ny)+(nz*nz));

    nx = nx/nn;
    ny = ny/nn;
    nz = nz/nn;

    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.x =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.x + nx);
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.y =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.y + ny);
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.z =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.z + nz);

    nn =  sqrt((Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.x*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.x)+(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.y*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.y)+(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.z*Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.z));

    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.x =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.x)/nn;
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.y =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.y)/nn;
    Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.z =(Faces[triangle_index].vtx[2].norm.z)/nn;

   }
```

if i add this loop just to see what goes on after the normals are calculated

```
for (int i =0 ; i<100;i++)
cout << "n "<<  Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x<< " "<< Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x <<" "<<  Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x <<"\n";
```

i get all zeros for the norm.x,y,z.
can anyone see whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `triangle_index` for your array indexing everywhere:

```
    ux= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].x - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].x ;
    uy= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].y - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].y ;
    uz= Faces[triangle_index].vtx[1].z - Faces[triangle_index].vtx[0].z ;
```

I think you want to use your loop index instead:

```
    ux= Faces[i].vtx[1].x - Faces[i].vtx[0].x ;
    uy= Faces[i].vtx[1].y - Faces[i].vtx[0].y ;
    uz= Faces[i].vtx[1].z - Faces[i].vtx[0].z ;
```

You need to fix this throughout the loop.

Also, to properly average the normals at the vertices, you should only accumulate them in this loop, and renormalize them in a new, second loop.  That is, put these two steps in two passes:

```
    Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x += nx;
    Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.y += ny;
    Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.z += nz;
```

and

```
    nn = sqrt( (Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x*Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x)
             + (Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.y*Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.y)
             + (Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.z*Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.z) );

    Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x /= nn;
    Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.y /= nn;
    Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.z /= nn;
```

That way each triangle that's coincident on that vertex carries equal weight.

Comment: Good catch. Yes that will get lots of zeros. And some divide-by-zeros.

Comment: Hi! thanx for the reply . you are right about that but it's a mistake i made here. because i just tryed to change somethings around and i hadnt cleaned it up yet. i did change it in the original code but now the normals are being calculated and they are not zero but they just look wrong though.

Comment: @user3085239 : BTW, if you're computing the vertex normals as the average of all the cross products at that vertex, you should _only_ accumulate during *this* loop, and then renormalize in a second pass.  If you renormalize for each new normal you add to the accumulation, then subsequent normals will carry too much weight.

Comment: im not sure myself to be honest. i thought it would work since i add and then i normalize. i couldnt think of a way to get the average of each vectror added instead of simply replacing them.

Comment: @user3085239 : I'm just suggesting to break it into two loops.  In the loop you have above, just do "norm.x = norm.x + nx", etc.  In the second loop, renormalize all the accumulated normals.

Comment: Joe Z thanx again! could you explain a little more? you mean i should add all the normalized normal vectors upon eachother and then in the end normalize the sum?

Comment: @user3085239 : I summarized the recommendation above.

Comment: ok i tryed what you say its maybe a little better but still it looks weird half smooth half not

Comment: Do you initialize all the normals to 0 before this loop?

Comment: the link above is the rendering i get its a highpoly model and you can see those little black triangles of uneven lighting ...

Comment: and this is the low poly counterpart http://cdn.imghack.se/images/cffa17a3385ae439ffbebb3ac23bd68b.png

Comment: @user3085239 : Wait a minute:  How do you actually handle multiple triangles coincident on a point?  I just realized that these normals at the vertices are embedded within the triangle's own structure.  But, you could have many triangles coincident on the same vertex.  You need to sum up all of _those_ normals and renormalize _that,_  pushing the merged results back to the individual triangles, shouldn't you? It shouldn't be possible for two triangles to have different shading meeting at the same point unless you're using different normals for that point for the different triangles.

Comment: Yes i did initialize in a different loop just before!

Comment: aaah damn! so i should parse all the struct and find all the points that are common to many faces?

Comment: or whats a faster way to do that? use faces as pointers to vertexes?

Comment: @user3085239 : Yes, or adopt a different data structure.  For example, put all your vertex coordinates in one array, and define your triangles as just indices into the vertex array.  Then, you can store your normals with the vertices in the vertex array.

Comment: ok i changed the whole thing. Faces as a struct has just an array vtx[3] that holds the pointers to a Vertece array. i didnt change the math or anthing just instead of :  Faces[i].vtx[0].norm.x
now i have  Points[ Faces[i].vtx[0] ].norm.x
and this is how it came out ..... :(
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/a120f6661f3eacfc9a8b84c0c626888b.png

Comment: @user3085239 : It doesn't even look like it's rendering the wireframe of the model correctly, let alone the shading.  Hmmm...  Are you sure you don't have an off-by-one somewhere between your vertex array and the indices you're using in your faces.vtx[] elements?

Comment: i think so. when i comment out the normals calculation and render the model just with ambient light the model is ok. the normals are messing up the thing i think. here is the code for reading the obj,getting normals and desplaying it. http://pastebin.com/nEJGvueV

Comment: my bad that last image it was my fault the wireframe was messed up. if i run it with the changes in structure with the code i pasted before this is the result . http://www.imghack.se/135805

Comment: @user3085239 : So that second loop to renormalize the accumulated normals:  It only needs to loop over the `Points` array, without looking at `Faces`.  ie. `for (i = 0; i < TotalConnectedPoints; i++) { Points[i] ... }`

Comment: @user3085239 : Is TotalConnectedPoints ever initialized to zero?  And, are you sure the vertex numbers on the `f` lines really do start at index 1, not 0?

Comment: @user3085239 : Also... instead of `atan`, you really ought to consider using `atan2`.

Comment: both TotalConnected and the triangleindex are initialized. and the f index thing definetly starts from 1. its the OBJ format. as for the atan ill change it but its just for the color anyway it shouldnt matter.

Comment: @user3085239 : I'll see if I see anything else fishy in your source.  I do see `while (!obj_file.eof())` when that should be `while (getline(obj_file,line))`, but the only thing that should cause is an extra point or extra vertex due to repeating one line at end of file.

Comment: ill change that as well. but even if it ran once more it wouldnt find any "v" or "f" so it wouldnt add a vertex. plus when running the displaymodel func without the glNormal() command the model looks smooth and as it should no extra points or anything like this

Comment: i really appreciat all the time youve put to reply to all this! ill check back tomorow. have a great day! thnx again! :D

Comment: @user3085239 : In that last image, I can't tell... is that progress?  :-)  It at least looks quite smooth.

Comment: no its not progress.i just commented out the normals assigning. i just wanted to show you that without the normals it is smooth and that all the reading and displaying is ok. so the fault is in the normals calculation part most probably

Comment: @user3085239 : Actually, is it possible to display it as a wireframe?  I suspect the model isn't quite right, but the smooth shading is hiding that.

Comment: @user3085239 : Hey... shouldn't your call for glNormal3f be before the call for glVertex3f?

Comment: here it is:
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/e32b5df32db83c298ae49b467a2595b6.png
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/d4ef196018941e8696f6f03d84b1681e.png

Comment: ok i cant thank you enough!!! i owe you one! :D 
i would have never looked again at the glnormal thing cuz i thought it was in the math! and just for the record since i posted so many screenshots here is the smooth one at last: 
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/a4563271d17299a8d815aed42a0d7a29.png
i can now sleep peacefully! thanx again!!!

Comment: @user3085239 : Glad to help.  I would have spotted it sooner, but I've only ever _written_ one OpenGL program, about 15 years ago, so I'm a little rusty. ;-)

Comment: hahaha! and im supposed to be studying this stuff for the course and i didnt even think about it! good thing i sent the whole thing on pastebin. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your code is perfectly valid, and that the problem lies in the direction of your normals. If you have two triangles in the same plane meeting at a point, then the normal computed at the vertex may be in the opposite direction (say if the points are in the XY plane, you could have one normal [0 0 1] and the other [0 0 -1]), depending on the order of the vertices.

When you add these two vectors, you may get a vector with a length of zero, which will give you trouble during normalization.

I would check the length of the vectors, and maybe choose a "dominant direction" to prevent this problem. Or always assign the value of the triangle "whose centroid is closest to the vertex", or "centroid with lowest X, Y value" - etc.

Comment: so you suggest i check if the vertex already has a normal assigned to it that is of bigger length and if so keep it as it is?

Comment: A vertex that is "almost parallel" to this one would be a sign of possible trouble. Parallel: abs(dot(n1, n2)) > 0.999 (say) - where n1 and n2 are normalized.

Comment: ok ill try this! but its 6 in the morning where i am and i cant look at code anymore! thanx alot. ill report back tomorow!